# Does Palantir Foundry plan to expand support of parameters linked to Restricted View columns and cross-filter groups to Reports?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I got a request to have cross-filtering on a report and found that it's not supported in reports, only in Contour analyses and dashboards. I'd really like to keep the additional functionality and style that comes with the report tool (rather than switch to a dashboard).

Any chance reports will be able to support cross-filtered parameters sometime soon?

Also on this topic, any chance restricted view might also be supported for parameters in reports too in the near future?